# Is $d\mu(x^{-1})$ an abuse of notation?

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

I'm wondering if it would be considered an abuse of notation to do something like,

$$ \int_G f(x^{-1})d\mu(x) = \int_G f(x) d\mu(x^{-1}) $$

where, for context, $\mu_G$ is a left Haar measure. I'm pretty terrible at measure theory and it seems from other questions here that this is definitely just wrong. Again, for context, I'm looking at locally compact groups and the convolution algebra $L_1(G)$, and the thorough proof is a bit too high above my pay grade but I suppose I've persisted. This is how I have used the notation in practise -

$$ 
= \int_G \triangle(x^{-1}) |f(x^{-1})| d\mu_G(x)
=\int_G \triangle(x)|f(x)| d\mu_G(x^{-1})
$$

any help would be great!

Comment: See the concept of [push-forward measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pushforward_measure). Since $x^{-1}$ here is nameless, we wouldn't write $d(f_*(\mu))$, unless you introduce the name $f(x)=x^{-1}$.